# Sonarqube 4.3 email notification not working

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to configure Sonarqube to notify the developers automatically by an email if their is a new issue assigned to their account.
On the settings-page I sent a test-email successfully and I recieved in my inbox  (gmail).
But inside the Sonar-Process the notification fails!
Does anyone have experience with that?

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410) ~[commons-email-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437) ~[commons-email-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.EmailNotificationChannel.send(EmailNotificationChannel.java:182) [sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.EmailNotificationChannel.deliver(EmailNotificationChannel.java:130) [sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.emailnotifications.EmailNotificationChannel.deliver(EmailNotificationChannel.java:106) [sonar-email-notifications-plugin-4.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.notifications.NotificationService.dispatch(NotificationService.java:197) [NotificationService.class:na]
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1970) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642) ~[mail-1.4.5.jar:1.4.5]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

just restart the server... this is not part of the documentation